# Quero saber do que estou sendo acusado?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, comunidade

Nessa questão [Como referenciar o host de hospedagem por variável, sem fixar no código Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/490178/como-referenciar-o-host-de-hospedagem-por-vari%c3%a1vel-sem-fixar-no-c%c3%b3digo-javascri)

O usuário fez nos comentários insinuações de que eu o prejudiquei e ainda usou o campo de respostas para reiterar as acusações contra minha pessoa.

- Eu não votei na pergunta.
- Eu não sinalizarei a pergunta.
- Eu não votei para fechar a pergunta.

**Prova de que não fiz nada que possa ser acusado:**

[image: Prova de que não agi contra a pergunta]

Única coisa que fiz na questão foi a editar removendo três(3) apostos que estavam sobrando no código:

Link para o histórico de revisões: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/490178/revisions

Comment: A conversa ficou longa e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122611/discussion-on-question-by-augusto-vasques-quero-saber-do-que-estou-sendo-acusado) - quem quiser ler ou acrescentar algo, queira usar o link fornecido.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Caro Augusto Vasques... espero que o SO tenha registro de mensagens, já que você apagou a sua mensagem onde me chamava, com todas as letras de "filho da ***a". Então me diga, isso é um comportamento aceitável? Realmente há muito o que melhorar no seu temperamento, assim como no meu e no de muitos seres humanos que conheço. Mas esse tipo de resposta te tira toda a razão. De qualquer forma, siga sua vida e seja feliz.

Comment: Em casos de violações do código de conduta, é importante sinalizar para a moderação, em vez de deixar o problema escalar (e nunca fazer réplica). Não estou me referindo só o caso específico, isto vale para qualquer conflito (e para todos os leitores).

Comment: Se houve isso mesmo que você mencionou, Paulo Monteiro, realmente foi uma atitude deplorável do cidadão.

Comment: Creio que stackoverflow tenha o registro de posts apagados, pois não deu tempo de fazer o print pois eu nem sabia que era possível denunciar. Infelizmente essa foi a resposta que obtive dele. Mas deixemos que cada um siga seu caminho em paz e que a vida se encarregue de recompensar cada u por suas atitudes. Grande abraço!